# kmm when using libres and using pictures, ios crashes

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to use resources with text data using the libres library, everything works fine, but when I try to use pictures, android displays them normally, but ios crashes

```
libres = "1.2.2"
libres = { module = "io.github.skeptick.libres:libres-compose", version.ref = "libres" }
libres = { id = "io.github.skeptick.libres", version.ref = "libres" }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Dpt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXnPX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBTji.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9R0t.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGEXN.png)

I did everything according to [this documentation](https://github.com/Skeptick/libres)

On Android everything works fine, but when I try to launch the application on iOS, the following error occurs

```
kotlin.IllegalStateException: LibresShared.bundle not found
    at 0   iosApp                              0x100b5a78f        kfun:kotlin.Throwable#<init>                    (kotlin.String?){} + 119
    at 1   iosApp                              0x100b53c7f        kfun:kotlin.Exception#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 115
    at 2   iosApp                              0x100b53e9f        kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 115
    at 3   iosApp                              0x100b5443f        kfun:kotlin.IllegalStateException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 115
    at 4   iosApp                              0x100cfaea3        kfun:io.github.skeptick.libres.images#bundleWithName__at__platform.Foundation.NSBundle.Companion(kotlin.String){}platform.Foundation.NSBundle + 755
    at 5   iosApp                              0x10001ce5f        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.images.SharedResourceImages.<init>$lambda$0#internal + 183
    at 6   iosApp                              0x10001cee3        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.images.SharedResourceImages.$<init>$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.invoke#internal + 63
    at 7   iosApp                              0x100c7dbcb        kfun:kotlin.Function0#invoke(){}1:0-trampoline + 99
    at 8   iosApp                              0x100b6c6f7        kfun:kotlin.native.concurrent.SynchronizedLazyImpl#<get-value>(){}1:0 + 707
    at 9   iosApp                              0x100c8049f        kfun:kotlin.Lazy#<get-value>(){}1:0-trampoline + 99
    at 10  iosApp                              0x10001c577        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.images.SharedResourceImages.<get-bundle>#internal + 191
    at 11  iosApp                              0x10001cb7f        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.images.SharedResourceImages#<get-wifi_on>(){}platform.UIKit.UIImage + 119
    at 12  iosApp                              0x1000723b7        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.screens.home_screen.HomeScreen.Content$lambda$3#internal + 11203
    at 13  iosApp                              0x10007e0ef        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.screens.home_screen.HomeScreen.$Content$lambda$3$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.invoke#internal + 119
    at 14  iosApp                              0x10007e243        kfun:com.example.testmultiplatfom.screens.home_screen.HomeScreen.$Content$lambda$3$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.$<bridge-UNNNB>invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}#internal + 159
    at 15  iosApp                              0x100c81913        kfun:kotlin.Function2#invoke(1:0;1:1){}1:2-trampoline + 115
    at 16  iosApp                              0x100eb818f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl#invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}kotlin.Any? + 587
    at 17  iosApp                              0x100ec5b5f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl#$<bridge-NNNNB>invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}kotlin.Any?(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Any?){}kotlin.Any? + 163
    at 18  iosApp                              0x100c81913        kfun:kotlin.Function2#invoke(1:0;1:1){}1:2-trampoline + 115
    at 19  iosApp                              0x10107a5a7        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose$lambda$1#internal + 887
    at 20  iosApp                              0x10107b1cb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.$subcompose$lambda$1$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$17.invoke#internal + 119
    at 21  iosApp                              0x10107b31f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.$subcompose$lambda$1$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$17.$<bridge-UNNNB>invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}#internal + 159
    at 22  iosApp                              0x100c81913        kfun:kotlin.Function2#invoke(1:0;1:1){}1:2-trampoline + 115
    at 23  iosApp                              0x100eb818f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl#invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}kotlin.Any? + 587
    at 24  iosApp                              0x100ec5b5f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl#$<bridge-NNNNB>invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}kotlin.Any?(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Any?){}kotlin.Any? + 163
    at 25  iosApp                              0x100c81913        kfun:kotlin.Function2#invoke(1:0;1:1){}1:2-trampoline + 115
    at 26  iosApp                              0x100eb7293        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime#invokeComposable(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){} + 215
    at 27  iosApp                              0x100dcc56b        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose#internal + 1935
    at 28  iosApp                              0x100dcb90b        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl#composeContent(androidx.compose.runtime.collection.IdentityArrayMap<androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl,androidx.compose.runtime.collection.IdentityArraySet<kotlin.Any>?>;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){} + 327
    at 29  iosApp                              0x100de3693        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl#composeContent(kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){} + 643
    at 30  iosApp                              0x100eccf63        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.ControlledComposition#composeContent(kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){}-trampoline + 99
    at 31  iosApp                              0x100e05827        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer#composeInitial(androidx.compose.runtime.ControlledComposition;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){} + 787
    at 32  iosApp                              0x100ecc4cb        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext#composeInitial(androidx.compose.runtime.ControlledComposition;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){}-trampoline + 67
    at 33  iosApp                              0x100dd1703        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial#internal + 195
    at 34  iosApp                              0x100ecc4cb        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext#composeInitial(androidx.compose.runtime.ControlledComposition;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){}-trampoline + 67
    at 35  iosApp                              0x100de2b5f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl#setContent(kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){} + 423
    at 36  iosApp                              0x100eccddf        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.Composition#setContent(kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){}-trampoline + 99
    at 37  iosApp                              0x101075cff        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto#internal + 391
    at 38  iosApp                              0x101075a03        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose#internal.28 + 967
    at 39  iosApp                              0x1010755fb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose#internal + 935
    at 40  iosApp                              0x10107512f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState#subcompose(kotlin.Any?;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){}kotlin.collections.List<androidx.compose.ui.layout.Measurable> + 2427
    at 41  iosApp                              0x101079213        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.Scope.subcompose#internal + 135
    at 42  iosApp                              0x1011afbb7        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeMeasureScope#subcompose(kotlin.Any?;kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Unit>){}kotlin.collections.List<androidx.compose.ui.layout.Measurable>-trampoline + 115
    at 43  iosApp                              0x10153ad3f        kfun:androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldLayout$lambda$6$lambda$5#internal + 2215
    at 44  iosApp                              0x10153eb8f        kfun:androidx.compose.material3.$ScaffoldLayout$lambda$6$lambda$5$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$11.invoke#internal + 171
    at 45  iosApp                              0x10153ee2f        kfun:androidx.compose.material3.$ScaffoldLayout$lambda$6$lambda$5$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$11.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope){}#internal + 99
    at 46  iosApp                              0x100c7c663        kfun:kotlin.Function1#invoke(1:0){}1:1-trampoline + 107
    at 47  iosApp                              0x101069e5f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope.object-1.placeChildren#internal + 827
    at 48  iosApp                              0x1011ae8d7        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureResult#placeChildren(){}-trampoline + 91
    at 49  iosApp                              0x10107af9b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.object-1.object-1.placeChildren#internal + 95
    at 50  iosApp                              0x1011ae8d7        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureResult#placeChildren(){}-trampoline + 91
    at 51  iosApp                              0x1010c132f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren$lambda$2#internal + 223
    at 52  iosApp                              0x1010c162b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$layoutChildren$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0.invoke#internal + 75
    at 53  iosApp                              0x1010c1727        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$layoutChildren$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0.$<bridge-UNN>invoke(){}#internal + 71
    at 54  iosApp                              0x100c7dbcb        kfun:kotlin.Function0#invoke(){}1:0-trampoline + 99
    at 55  iosApp                              0x100e7cf3f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot.Companion#observe(kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function0<0:0>){0§<kotlin.Any?>}0:0 + 943
    at 56  iosApp                              0x100eb05ef        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.ObservedScopeMap.observe#internal + 819
    at 57  iosApp                              0x100eae0ff        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<kotlin.Any>} + 679
    at 58  iosApp                              0x1010fb7fb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerScope>} + 227
    at 59  iosApp                              0x1010fafc3        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeLayoutSnapshotReads(androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode;kotlin.Boolean;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){} + 411
    at 60  iosApp                              0x1010bbfff        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate#layoutChildren(){} + 979
    at 61  iosApp                              0x1010bd4f3        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate#onNodePlaced(){} + 1675
    at 62  iosApp                              0x101094a8f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){} + 291
    at 63  iosApp                              0x1011af337        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){}-trampoline + 75
    at 64  iosApp                              0x10106d133        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#place__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float){} + 423
    at 65  iosApp                              0x1010c1563        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator$lambda$4#internal + 315
    at 66  iosApp                              0x1010c18ab        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$placeOuterCoordinator$lambda$4$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$2.invoke#internal + 83
    at 67  iosApp                              0x1010c19db        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$placeOuterCoordinator$lambda$4$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$2.$<bridge-UNN>invoke(){}#internal + 71
    at 68  iosApp                              0x100c7dbcb        kfun:kotlin.Function0#invoke(){}1:0-trampoline + 99
    at 69  iosApp                              0x100e7cf3f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot.Companion#observe(kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function0<0:0>){0§<kotlin.Any?>}0:0 + 943
    at 70  iosApp                              0x100eb05ef        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.ObservedScopeMap.observe#internal + 819
    at 71  iosApp                              0x100eae0ff        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<kotlin.Any>} + 679
    at 72  iosApp                              0x1010fb7fb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerScope>} + 227
    at 73  iosApp                              0x1010fb26b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads(androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode;kotlin.Boolean;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){} + 411
    at 74  iosApp                              0x1010bf24b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator#internal + 835
    at 75  iosApp                              0x1010beedf        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){} + 1023
    at 76  iosApp                              0x1011af337        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){}-trampoline + 75
    at 77  iosApp                              0x10106d133        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#place__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float){} + 423
    at 78  iosApp                              0x10106d217        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#place$default__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Int){} + 183
    at 79  iosApp                              0x1013150bf        kfun:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.placeInBox#internal + 583
    at 80  iosApp                              0x1013177eb        kfun:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.boxMeasurePolicy$lambda$5$lambda$3#internal + 359
    at 81  iosApp                              0x1013193e3        kfun:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.$boxMeasurePolicy$lambda$5$lambda$3$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$7.invoke#internal + 119
    at 82  iosApp                              0x101319583        kfun:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.$boxMeasurePolicy$lambda$5$lambda$3$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$7.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope){}#internal + 99
    at 83  iosApp                              0x100c7c663        kfun:kotlin.Function1#invoke(1:0){}1:1-trampoline + 107
    at 84  iosApp                              0x101069e5f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope.object-1.placeChildren#internal + 827
    at 85  iosApp                              0x1011ae8d7        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureResult#placeChildren(){}-trampoline + 91
    at 86  iosApp                              0x1010c132f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren$lambda$2#internal + 223
    at 87  iosApp                              0x1010c162b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$layoutChildren$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0.invoke#internal + 75
    at 88  iosApp                              0x1010c1727        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$layoutChildren$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0.$<bridge-UNN>invoke(){}#internal + 71
    at 89  iosApp                              0x100c7dbcb        kfun:kotlin.Function0#invoke(){}1:0-trampoline + 99
    at 90  iosApp                              0x100e7cf3f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot.Companion#observe(kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function0<0:0>){0§<kotlin.Any?>}0:0 + 943
    at 91  iosApp                              0x100eb05ef        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.ObservedScopeMap.observe#internal + 819
    at 92  iosApp                              0x100eae0ff        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<kotlin.Any>} + 679
    at 93  iosApp                              0x1010fb7fb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerScope>} + 227
    at 94  iosApp                              0x1010fafc3        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeLayoutSnapshotReads(androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode;kotlin.Boolean;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){} + 411
    at 95  iosApp                              0x1010bbfff        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate#layoutChildren(){} + 979
    at 96  iosApp                              0x1010bd4f3        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate#onNodePlaced(){} + 1675
    at 97  iosApp                              0x101094a8f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){} + 291
    at 98  iosApp                              0x1011af337        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){}-trampoline + 75
    at 99  iosApp                              0x10106da4b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#placeWithLayer__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>){} + 475
    at 100 iosApp                              0x10106dbdf        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#placeWithLayer$default__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Int){} + 359
    at 101 iosApp                              0x10102a2c3        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure$lambda$1#internal + 223
    at 102 iosApp                              0x10102a4d3        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.$measure$lambda$1$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$2.invoke#internal + 103
    at 103 iosApp                              0x10102a5eb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.$measure$lambda$1$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$2.$<bridge-UNNN>invoke(androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope){}#internal + 99
    at 104 iosApp                              0x100c7c663        kfun:kotlin.Function1#invoke(1:0){}1:1-trampoline + 107
    at 105 iosApp                              0x101069e5f        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope.object-1.placeChildren#internal + 827
    at 106 iosApp                              0x1011ae8d7        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureResult#placeChildren(){}-trampoline + 91
    at 107 iosApp                              0x10109ca17        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){} + 871
    at 108 iosApp                              0x1011af337        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){}-trampoline + 75
    at 109 iosApp                              0x10106d133        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#place__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float){} + 423
    at 110 iosApp                              0x1010c1563        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator$lambda$4#internal + 315
    at 111 iosApp                              0x1010c18ab        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$placeOuterCoordinator$lambda$4$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$2.invoke#internal + 83
    at 112 iosApp                              0x1010c19db        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.$placeOuterCoordinator$lambda$4$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$2.$<bridge-UNN>invoke(){}#internal + 71
    at 113 iosApp                              0x100c7dbcb        kfun:kotlin.Function0#invoke(){}1:0-trampoline + 99
    at 114 iosApp                              0x100e7cf3f        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot.Companion#observe(kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Any,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Function0<0:0>){0§<kotlin.Any?>}0:0 + 943
    at 115 iosApp                              0x100eb05ef        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.ObservedScopeMap.observe#internal + 819
    at 116 iosApp                              0x100eae0ff        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<kotlin.Any>} + 679
    at 117 iosApp                              0x1010fb7fb        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeReads(0:0;kotlin.Function1<0:0,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){0§<androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerScope>} + 227
    at 118 iosApp                              0x1010fb26b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver#observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads(androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode;kotlin.Boolean;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Unit>){} + 411
    at 119 iosApp                              0x1010bf24b        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator#internal + 835
    at 120 iosApp                              0x1010beedf        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.MeasurePassDelegate#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){} + 1023
    at 121 iosApp                              0x1011af337        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable#placeAt(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.graphics.GraphicsLayerScope,kotlin.Unit>?){}-trampoline + 75
    at 122 iosApp                              0x10106d133        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#place__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float){} + 423
    at 123 iosApp                              0x10106d217        kfun:androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.PlacementScope#place$default__at__androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset;kotlin.Float;kotlin.Int){} + 183
    at 124 iosApp                              0x1013150bf        kfun:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.placeInBox#internal + 583
    at 125 iosApp                              0x1013177eb        kfun:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.boxMeasurePolicy$lambda$5$lambda$3#internal + 359
```

I don’t understand what the problem is and I haven’t found a solution anywhere on the Internet

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)